# React js call a route with <link> material ui

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Hello I have an app bar with a toolbar and buttons where I would be my menu added a  to my button to call a route that set in my route

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Header/>
    <Navigation/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route path="/xd" component={About} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>

    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

this is my path:

`<Route path="/xd" component={About} exact={true}` />

and this is my navbar:

```
export default function Navigation() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar} >
          <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Toolbar >
<Link to="/xd">
 <Button  className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false"  color="secondary">
   Home
</Button>
</Link>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised"  disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
        </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    );
}
```

when i click one of the buttons i want to update only the content container
I don't know if I'm doing correct

Comment: Wrapping those buttons in the `Link` components should have the effect you're looking for. Is that not working?

Comment: it's not and I don't know why :(

Comment: So to confirm, if you are on path `"/"` and you click that first button component wrapped in `<Link to="/xd">` - your path does not change to `"/xd"`?

Comment: yes dont change to /xd

Comment: And my route is normal, I think it's a problem with my navbar

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing your `Link` and `Button` components are interfering with each other. Usually buttons have a handler method such as `onClick` available that lets you run code. You can try using the click handler for your buttons to change the history or location of your app (programatically route) or just use a piece of text instead of the button to get it working correctly. Then add in those material-ui components that give your app the appearance you want.

Comment: Can you check my route?

I basically want to have only one container to display all content
ie update only the content
and not the whole page
Can you check if I'm on the right track?

And if you can add a response with onclick for me to vote positive

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track here, with your `navbar` and `header` being adjacent to your `switch` statement. What I think is maybe your `Link` component and your material-ui `Button` component might be interfering with each other.

Material UI explains more here:
https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library

But, you could also try to route in your app with the onClick handler of the `button` itself:

```
<Button className={classes.button} onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('/xd')}} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false"  color="secondary">
   About
</Button>
```